# REST API a request to add/subtract from a field

Tags: api, rest, patch, put

What's considered best for an hydration resource that saves each day, in which the user may add/subtract the amount he drank during that specific day. each resource row in the database looks like:

userid, date, amount

1, 2021-05-23 1000

a. A single PUT method that:

1. Creates the resource (with the given amount) if it doesn't exist yet for the particular date.
2. Updates the resource whole amount
3. Deletes the resource for that date if the amount is below 0.

b. A POST request to create the resource with the given amount, and a PATCH request to update the whole amount and delete if the amount is below 0

c. A POST request to create the resource with the given amount and a PATCH request to update the amount like:

```
{
   "operation": "add"/"subtract",
   "amount": 200
}
```

And again if the amount falls below 0 then delete the resource

d. Other possible solution?

I don't see how DELETE is related here because the user doesn't type the amount he drank, he can add/remove a given amount so I'm trying to figure out what works best for this scenario.

**EDIT:**

The api will function as a backend for an android app. The user will see a few built-in buttons. 100 ml, 300 ml, 500 ml & custom amount.

As he clicks one of these the amount should increase. on the database it will be saved as a single row BUT the user will see a one entry for each click.

My question is what's the best way for doing such thing. is a PATCH or PUT that does a DELETE if the amount is below 0 considered normal? what's better, POST and then PATCH or PUT?

another possible solution that is similar to opt. C, Is to just remove the operation field and allow the amount to be either positive or negative, and that should simplify things a little but is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you need simple, and minified code you shall use the method A. If you want to have everything organized (Better Solution) Use Method B or C, I suggest method C because it allows you to delete resource if user subtracted all what he drank, plus, it saves any positive (Thus, possible) amount.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just never heard or seen something like opt. C, will it does seems very logical I don't know if its considered a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

> d. Other possible solution?

How would you do it with a web site?

You'd probably have an HTML document with a form in it, the form would allow your customer to input the information of interest, using general purpose controls.  When the customer clicked the submit button, the browser would take the data in the input controls, the metadata of the form itself, and create the appropriate HTTP request to share that information with the server.

That would be an HTTP POST request, and the target resource could be anything - the server would specify the resource as part of the description of the form in HTML.  But a *useful* resource to choose would be one that is going to be changed when the request is successfully handled (because that allows us to leverage the [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) rules already defined in HTTP).

Notice that, on the web, we normally use POST both for requests that might create a new resource, and requests that might change an existing resource.

---

Both PUT and PATCH have remote authoring semantics.  You can design your resource model so that this works for what you want, but its a bit different.

Instead of getting forms, we actually edit documents - use a GET to load the text/html/json/whatever into your editor, make changes to your local copy, and then share your copy with the server.

So if the resource were a list of amounts, then in the client you would do the add/subtract yourself, put the new correct amount the document, and then send either your copy of the document (PUT), or a copy of the changes you have made (PATCH).

A web analogy would be to GET a copy of a web page, change the TITLE element in your local copy, and then PUT your version of the page back to the same URI that you fetched it from (or PATCH that same URI with a patch document that describes the change you made).

You don't see that very often, of course.  If it's your own web site, you are more likely to change the page through your release pipeline, rather than your web front end.  For other web sites, well... you're probably looking at it in a general purpose web browser, rather than a general purpose editor.

Comment: Hi, your response is much appreciated. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my question, this api will function as a backend server for an android app. I appreciate your long and detailed answer, but I'm mainly interested about these lines "So if the resource... you have made (PATCH)." I'll update my question to make it clearer. thanks!